# Search marker info box

Tags: google-maps, search, google-maps-api-3, marker

Does map API has possiblity to search information from within info box for example marker infobox?

My infoboxes display some text information. I just want to search this text and show on the map only markers which has the text I'm looking for. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: Not very clear what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for

```
//Build html for Infowindow
      var html = "<b> Text </b> <br>;
      html = html + "<input type=\"text\" id=\"addressInput\" size=\"10\"/>;
      html = html + "<select id=\"radiusSelect\">";
      html = html + "<option value=\"25\" selected>25mi</option>";
      html = html + "<option value=\"100\">100mi</option>";
      html = html + "<option value=\"200\">200mi</option>";
      html = html + "</select>";
      html = html + "<br/><button onclick='doIt()'>Do It</button>";
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
        position: point,
      });
      //marker array to allow clearin markers
       markerArray.push(marker);
       bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
```

Comment: Thanks but I didn't say I don't know how to create info window... I have info windows and I wanted to search the text inside of them. I think the question was clear. As I couldn't find any google method to do it I have just put my info windows copies into an array and did search on the array content instead.

Comment: You can create an answer to your question with your method. This will help anyone else with the same problem. You can also edit your question to make it more explicit. This may enable the question to be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any google method to do it I have just put my info windows copies into an array and did search on the array content instead.